# How to provision hardware for virtualbox?

Tags: performance, virtualbox

In our organisation we are planning to get new machines for developers. The requirements are that the developers should be able to run upto 3 VirtualBox virtual machines in parallel. The usage pattern of the 3 machines is as follows :

1. A developer machine with 2 cpu's and 4gb ram and CentOS 6.2. The developer will use Eclipse, and many other services run on this machine like tomcat, qmail etc.
2. The other 2 are test machines with 2 cpu's each and 2 gb ram. The test machines do not have X running on it. They also have many services running like tomcat, qmail etc.

Now we have got a new hardware to evaluate. The configuration for the new machine is :

```
Intel Core i3 Second generation 2100 cpu  3.10ghz. 
16 gb ram.
1 Tb HDD.
```

We have installed CentOS 6.2 64 bit as the host OS.

In /proc/cpuinfo it shows 2 cores & 4 processors:

```
cpu cores       : 2
processor       : 0
processor       : 1
processor       : 2
processor       : 3
```

When running the above 3 virtual machines on the new hardware, we see performance degradation intermittently and some times while rebooting.

I think the ram and hdd are ok, but we are falling short in terms of CPU power. The hdd is sata.

Can anybody suggest whether my processor is sufficient for the workload or should I get a different one with more cores? Or should I go for Core I5 ?

Thanks,
Amol.

Answer (score 1):

"I think" is never really good enough

top or [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) will let you know whether processor or ram is a bottleneck - watch ram usage, processor usage, swap and load averages.

[iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) will let you know if its the hard drive - or at least what processes and what speed data transfer happens.

Let your devs do their thing, watch, and find out *what* is the bottleneck - there isn't really enough information to decide where the issue is